# Trying to subset and/or filter (essentially separate) a data frame object which has already been tokenized

Tags: r, regex, subset

Trying to subset and/or filter (essentially separate) a data frame object which has already been tokenized so that each row of the df either begins with a Senator and what they said, a Senator and the bill they’re proposing, and a header of the Congressional record.

What I need to do is keep the rows that identify a senator and their speech. When I apply the subset or filter function to my df, the output has no content (see script for description).

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

#this is the list of senator names with regex
## "^" to indicate that the names are at the begginning of the string
## "\\s" to indicate that there should be a white space after the ":"
## "(.*) to indicate that it should include all following content
sen_names <- c("^Mr. McCONNELL (R; Kentucky):\\s(.*)","^Mr. JOHNSON (D; South Dakota):\\s(.*)","^Mr. NICKLES (R; Oklahoma):\\s(.*)","^Mr. LEAHY (D; Vermont):\\s(.*)","^Mr. CONRAD (D; North Dakota):\\s(.*)","^Mrs. BOXER (D; California):\\s(.*)","^Mrs. BOXER (D; California):\\s(.*)","^Mr. SHELBY (R:\\s(.*) Alabama):\\s(.*)","^Ms. MURKOWSKI (R; Alaska):\\s(.*)","^Mr. STEVENS (R; Alaska):\\s(.*)","^Mr. KYL (R; Arizona):\\s(.*)","^Mr. McCAIN (R; Arizona):\\s(.*)","^Mr. PRYOR (D; Arkansas):\\s(.*)","^Mrs. LINCOLN (D; Arkansas):\\s(.*)","^Mrs. FEINSTEIN (D; California):\\s(.*)","^Mr. ALLARD (R; Colorado):\\s(.*)","^Mr. CAMPBELL (R; Colorado):\\s(.*)","^Mr. DODD (D; Connecticut):\\s(.*)","^Mr. LIEBERMAN (D; Connecticut):\\s(.*)","^Mr. BIDEN (D; Delaware):\\s(.*)","^Mr. CARPER (D; Delaware):\\s(.*)","^Mr. L GRAHAM (R; South Carolina):\\s(.*)","^Mr. B GRAHAM (D; Florida):\\s(.*)","^Mr. C NELSON (D; Florida):\\s(.*)","^Mr. B NELSON (D; Nebraska):\\s(.*)","^Mr. CHAMBLISS (R; Georgia):\\s(.*)","^Mr. MILLER (D; Georgia):\\s(.*)","^Mr. AKAKA (D; Hawaii):\\s(.*)","^Mr. INOUYE (D; Hawaii):\\s(.*)","^Mr. CRAIG (R; Idaho):\\s(.*)","^Mr. CRAPO (R; Idaho):\\s(.*)","^Mr. DURBIN (D; Illinois):\\s(.*)","^Mr. FITZGERALD (R; Illinois):\\s(.*)","^Mr. BAYH (D; Indiana):\\s(.*)","^Mr. LUGAR (R; Indiana):\\s(.*)","^Mr. GRASSLEY (R; Iowa):\\s(.*)","^Mr. HARKIN (D; Iowa):\\s(.*)","^Mr. BROWNBACK (R; Kansas):\\s(.*)","^Mr. ROBERTS (R; Kansas):\\s(.*)","^Mr. BUNNING (R; Kentucky):\\s(.*)","^Mr. BREAUX (D; Louisiana):\\s(.*)","^Ms. LANDRIEU (D; Louisiana):\\s(.*)","^Ms. COLLINS (R; Maine):\\s(.*)","^Ms. SNOWE (R; Maine):\\s(.*)","^Ms. MIKULSKI (D; Maryland):\\s(.*)","^Mr. SARBANES (D; Maryland):\\s(.*)","^Mr. KENNEDY (D; Massachusetts):\\s(.*)","^Mr. KERRY (D; Massachusetts):\\s(.*)","^Ms. STABENOW (D; Michigan):\\s(.*)","^Mr. LEVIN (D; Michigan):\\s(.*)","^Mr. DAYTON (D; Minnesota):\\s(.*)","^Mr. COLEMAN (R; Minnesota):\\s(.*)","^Mr. COCHRAN (R; Mississippi):\\s(.*)","^Mr. COCHRAN (R; Mississippi):\\s(.*)","^Mr. TALENT (R; Missouri):\\s(.*)","^Mr. BOND (R; Missouri):\\s(.*)","^Mr. BAUCUS (D; Montana):\\s(.*)","^Mr. BURNS (R; Montana):\\s(.*)","^Mr. HAGEL (R; Nebraska):\\s(.*)","^Mr. ENSIGN (R; Nevada):\\s(.*)","^Mr. REID (D; Nevada):\\s(.*)","^Mr. GREGG (R; New Hampshire):\\s(.*)","^Mr. SUNUNU (R; New Hampshire):\\s(.*)","^Mr. CORZINE (D; New Jersey):\\s(.*)","^Mr. LAUTENBERG (D; New Jersey):\\s(.*)","^Mr. BINGAMAN (D; New Mexico):\\s(.*)","^Mr. DOMENICI (R; New Mexico):\\s(.*)","^Mrs. CLINTON (D; New York):\\s(.*)","^Mr. SCHUMER (D; New York):\\s(.*)","^Mr. SCHUMER (D; New York):\\s(.*)","^Mr. SCHUMER (D; New York):\\s(.*)","^Mr. DORGAN (D; North Dakota):\\s(.*)","^Mr. DEWINE (R; Ohio):\\s(.*)","^Mr. VOINOVICH (R; Ohio):\\s(.*)","^Mr. INHOFE (R; Oklahoma):\\s(.*)","^Mr. SMITH (R; Oregon):\\s(.*)","^Mr. WYDEN (D; Oregon):\\s(.*)","^Mr. SANTORUM (R; Pennsylvania):\\s(.*)","^Mr. SPECTER (R; Pennsylvania):\\s(.*)","^Mr. CHAFEE (R; Rhode Island):\\s(.*)","^Mr. REED (D; Rhode Island):\\s(.*)","^Mr. HOLLINGS (D; South Carolina):\\s(.*)","^Mr. DASCHLE (D; South Dakota):\\s(.*)","^Mr. FRIST (R; Tennessee):\\s(.*)","^Mr. ALEXANDER (R; Tennessee):\\s(.*)","^Mr. CORNYN (R; Texas):\\s(.*)","^Mrs. HUTCHISON (R; Texas):\\s(.*)","^Mr. BENNETT (R; Utah):\\s(.*)","^Mr. HATCH (R; Utah):\\s(.*)","^Mr. JEFFORDS (I; Vermont):\\s(.*)","^Mr. ALLEN (R; Virginia):\\s(.*)","^Mr. WARNER (R; Virginia):\\s(.*)","^Ms. CANTWELL (D; Washington):\\s(.*)","^Ms. CANTWELL (D; Washington):\\s(.*)","^Mr. BYRD (D; West Virginia):\\s(.*)","^Mr. ROCKEFELLER (D; West Virginia):\\s(.*)","^Mr. FEINGOLD (D; Wisconsin):\\s(.*)","^Mr. KOHL (D; Wisconsin):\\s(.*)","^Mr. ENZI (R; Wyoming):\\s(.*)","^Mr. THOMAS (R; Wyoming):\\s(.*)")

#this imports the column from a tokenized dataframe
##the tokenized df is a single congressional record
##and it has already been split, I just need the ones that...
#... start with the names and are speeches rather than descriptions...
#... of legislation
aug_01_2003_speeches <- data.frame(aug_01_2003_tkns$cleaned)
colnames(aug_01_2003_speeches) <- c("speeches")
View(aug_01_2003_speeches)


#tried running through subset()
##OUTPUT -> "<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)"
#NOTE: original object names were aug_o1_speeches
#... changed here for clarity when calling the object
aug_01_2003_x <- subset(aug_01_2003_speeches, sen_names, select = speeches)
aug_01_2003_x <- subset(aug_01_2003_speeches, subset = sen_names, select = speeches)
aug_01_2003_x <- subset(aug_01_2003_speeches, speeches %in% sen_names)
aug_01_2003_x

#tried running through filter()
##OUTPUT -> "<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)"
aug_01_2003_x <- filter(aug_01_2003_speeches, speeches %in% sen_names, .preserve = T)
aug_01_2003_x

#there are 100 names here, so running each one individually...
#... wouldn't be the best solution in the world
```

I have uploaded a test environment to Google Drive that includes the list/dictionary of senators and one of the tokenized dfs. This is already setup with regex (and maybe this is where I’m going wrong?) It is accessible here: [test environment](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mTZuu281JPDrEIwZlo_rgaRtV7X5EOMu/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: in `subset` you are supposed to pass a logical condition to filter out the rows. In your case, you can use `grepl` to apply your regex on the column with senator names to get the logical vector for subsetting.

Comment: @AdroMine I had already tried that previously and got this error message using the following code:

`aug_01_2003_x <- subset(aug_01_2003_speeches, grepl(sen_names, speeches, ignore.case = F))

output -> "Warning message:
In grepl(sen_names, speeches, ignore.case = F) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"`

Comment: The first 13 lines of code inside the question are irrelevant, and make the post too long, which may lower the chances of getting helpful answers. Please remove all these data wrangling steps and rather supply a proper reproducible dataset. Paste the output of `dput(aug_01_2003_speeches)`, or maybe `dput(head(aug_01_2003_speeches, x))` (in the later example, make x as long as necessary to get at least two different senators)

Comment: @GuedesBF the output of `dput(aug_01_2003_speeches)` is extremely long and `dput(head(aug_01_2003_speeches, x))` is the object that’s being created from the error, thus has a value of 0. `structure(list(speeches = character(0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = integer(0))` Those first lines you have asked me to delete explain what the objects are because I don't know where the error is occurring & both objects hold a large amount of data (9.2KB for the first, 579.3KB for the second). I could try the output of `test_text <- dput(aug_01_2003_speeches[1:25,])` but that's about 300 lines of text

Comment: If `dput(aug_01_2003_speeches[1:25,])` works, dput `dput(head(aug_01_2003_speeches, x))` in which x is the minimal value to reproduce the problem should output a valid data.frame too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regexes for the `sen_names` were wrong by just a bit. You were almost there.

We have to escape the parenthesis and literal dots, as these are special characters. I also see no reason for `(.*)` at the end of the patterns.
After correcting the regexes, we can `paste` all sen_names into a single character scalar, separeted by the OR special character (`|`), then do the matching on this single char element.

With the following code, I could filter a data.frame of just two rows. I believe this example with two sen_names is an adequate minimal reprex:

```
sen_names <- c("^Mr\\. McCONNELL \\(R; Kentucky\\):\\s","^Mr\\. JOHNSON \\(D; South Dakota\\):\\s")
consolidated_sen_names <- paste(sen_names, collapse = "|")

aug_01_2003_speeches |> 
    filter(str_detect(speeches, consolidated_sen_names)) |>
    tibble()

# A tibble: 2 × 1
  speeches                                                                                                                             
  <chr>                                                                                                                                
1 Mr. McCONNELL (R; Kentucky): Mr. President, I listened with great interest to Senator Frist (R; Tennessee)'s comments about Bob Hope…
2 Mr. McCONNELL (R; Kentucky): Mr. President, on another subject, I commend Senator Frist (R; Tennessee), before he leaves the floor, …
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the `dplyr` and `stringr` packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# Clean state, affiliation, and trailing regex from sen_names
sen_names <- c("^Mr. McCONNELL (R; Kentucky):\\s(.*)","^Mr. JOHNSON (D; South Dakota):\\s(.*)","^Mr. NICKLES (R; Oklahoma):\\s(.*)","^Mr. LEAHY (D; Vermont):\\s(.*)","^Mr. CONRAD (D; North Dakota):\\s(.*)","^Mrs. BOXER (D; California):\\s(.*)","^Mrs. BOXER (D; California):\\s(.*)","^Mr. SHELBY (R:\\s(.*) Alabama):\\s(.*)","^Ms. MURKOWSKI (R; Alaska):\\s(.*)","^Mr. STEVENS (R; Alaska):\\s(.*)","^Mr. KYL (R; Arizona):\\s(.*)","^Mr. McCAIN (R; Arizona):\\s(.*)","^Mr. PRYOR (D; Arkansas):\\s(.*)","^Mrs. LINCOLN (D; Arkansas):\\s(.*)","^Mrs. FEINSTEIN (D; California):\\s(.*)","^Mr. ALLARD (R; Colorado):\\s(.*)","^Mr. CAMPBELL (R; Colorado):\\s(.*)","^Mr. DODD (D; Connecticut):\\s(.*)","^Mr. LIEBERMAN (D; Connecticut):\\s(.*)","^Mr. BIDEN (D; Delaware):\\s(.*)","^Mr. CARPER (D; Delaware):\\s(.*)","^Mr. L GRAHAM (R; South Carolina):\\s(.*)","^Mr. B GRAHAM (D; Florida):\\s(.*)","^Mr. C NELSON (D; Florida):\\s(.*)","^Mr. B NELSON (D; Nebraska):\\s(.*)","^Mr. CHAMBLISS (R; Georgia):\\s(.*)","^Mr. MILLER (D; Georgia):\\s(.*)","^Mr. AKAKA (D; Hawaii):\\s(.*)","^Mr. INOUYE (D; Hawaii):\\s(.*)","^Mr. CRAIG (R; Idaho):\\s(.*)","^Mr. CRAPO (R; Idaho):\\s(.*)","^Mr. DURBIN (D; Illinois):\\s(.*)","^Mr. FITZGERALD (R; Illinois):\\s(.*)","^Mr. BAYH (D; Indiana):\\s(.*)","^Mr. LUGAR (R; Indiana):\\s(.*)","^Mr. GRASSLEY (R; Iowa):\\s(.*)","^Mr. HARKIN (D; Iowa):\\s(.*)","^Mr. BROWNBACK (R; Kansas):\\s(.*)","^Mr. ROBERTS (R; Kansas):\\s(.*)","^Mr. BUNNING (R; Kentucky):\\s(.*)","^Mr. BREAUX (D; Louisiana):\\s(.*)","^Ms. LANDRIEU (D; Louisiana):\\s(.*)","^Ms. COLLINS (R; Maine):\\s(.*)","^Ms. SNOWE (R; Maine):\\s(.*)","^Ms. MIKULSKI (D; Maryland):\\s(.*)","^Mr. SARBANES (D; Maryland):\\s(.*)","^Mr. KENNEDY (D; Massachusetts):\\s(.*)","^Mr. KERRY (D; Massachusetts):\\s(.*)","^Ms. STABENOW (D; Michigan):\\s(.*)","^Mr. LEVIN (D; Michigan):\\s(.*)","^Mr. DAYTON (D; Minnesota):\\s(.*)","^Mr. COLEMAN (R; Minnesota):\\s(.*)","^Mr. COCHRAN (R; Mississippi):\\s(.*)","^Mr. COCHRAN (R; Mississippi):\\s(.*)","^Mr. TALENT (R; Missouri):\\s(.*)","^Mr. BOND (R; Missouri):\\s(.*)","^Mr. BAUCUS (D; Montana):\\s(.*)","^Mr. BURNS (R; Montana):\\s(.*)","^Mr. HAGEL (R; Nebraska):\\s(.*)","^Mr. ENSIGN (R; Nevada):\\s(.*)","^Mr. REID (D; Nevada):\\s(.*)","^Mr. GREGG (R; New Hampshire):\\s(.*)","^Mr. SUNUNU (R; New Hampshire):\\s(.*)","^Mr. CORZINE (D; New Jersey):\\s(.*)","^Mr. LAUTENBERG (D; New Jersey):\\s(.*)","^Mr. BINGAMAN (D; New Mexico):\\s(.*)","^Mr. DOMENICI (R; New Mexico):\\s(.*)","^Mrs. CLINTON (D; New York):\\s(.*)","^Mr. SCHUMER (D; New York):\\s(.*)","^Mr. SCHUMER (D; New York):\\s(.*)","^Mr. SCHUMER (D; New York):\\s(.*)","^Mr. DORGAN (D; North Dakota):\\s(.*)","^Mr. DEWINE (R; Ohio):\\s(.*)","^Mr. VOINOVICH (R; Ohio):\\s(.*)","^Mr. INHOFE (R; Oklahoma):\\s(.*)","^Mr. SMITH (R; Oregon):\\s(.*)","^Mr. WYDEN (D; Oregon):\\s(.*)","^Mr. SANTORUM (R; Pennsylvania):\\s(.*)","^Mr. SPECTER (R; Pennsylvania):\\s(.*)","^Mr. CHAFEE (R; Rhode Island):\\s(.*)","^Mr. REED (D; Rhode Island):\\s(.*)","^Mr. HOLLINGS (D; South Carolina):\\s(.*)","^Mr. DASCHLE (D; South Dakota):\\s(.*)","^Mr. FRIST (R; Tennessee):\\s(.*)","^Mr. ALEXANDER (R; Tennessee):\\s(.*)","^Mr. CORNYN (R; Texas):\\s(.*)","^Mrs. HUTCHISON (R; Texas):\\s(.*)","^Mr. BENNETT (R; Utah):\\s(.*)","^Mr. HATCH (R; Utah):\\s(.*)","^Mr. JEFFORDS (I; Vermont):\\s(.*)","^Mr. ALLEN (R; Virginia):\\s(.*)","^Mr. WARNER (R; Virginia):\\s(.*)","^Ms. CANTWELL (D; Washington):\\s(.*)","^Ms. CANTWELL (D; Washington):\\s(.*)","^Mr. BYRD (D; West Virginia):\\s(.*)","^Mr. ROCKEFELLER (D; West Virginia):\\s(.*)","^Mr. FEINGOLD (D; Wisconsin):\\s(.*)","^Mr. KOHL (D; Wisconsin):\\s(.*)","^Mr. ENZI (R; Wyoming):\\s(.*)","^Mr. THOMAS (R; Wyoming):\\s(.*)")
sen_names <- gsub("\\(.*","",sen_names)
sen_names <- trimws(sen_names)

# Add "or" operand | to sen_names
sen_names <-  paste0("(", paste(sen_names, collapse = "|"), ")")

# Create new filtered object using sen_names
speeches_only <- aug_01_2003_speeches %>%
  filter(str_detect(speeches, sen_names))

# Result
data.frame(substr(speeches_only[1:10,1], 1, 50))

                substr.speeches_only.1.10..1...1..50.
1  Mr. FRIST (R; Tennessee): Mr. President, this morn
2  Mr. FRIST (R; Tennessee): Mr. President, I ask una
3  Mr. FRIST (R; Tennessee): Mr. President, I take th
4  Mr. McCONNELL (R; Kentucky): Mr. President, I list
5  Mr. McCONNELL (R; Kentucky): Mr. President, on ano
6  Mr. BINGAMAN (D; New Mexico): Mr. President, let m
7  Mr. C NELSON (D; Florida): Mr. President, I ask un
8  Mr. C NELSON (D; Florida): Mr. President, we have 
9  Mr. C NELSON (D; Florida): Mr. President, I was lo
10 Mr. TALENT (R; Missouri): Mr. President, it is my
```

In total, 134 speeches matching your criteria were found in the example dataset you provided.

Comment: Note that the reference to state and affiliation was stripped from the senator names in order to simplify the "sen_names" object passed to `str_detect()`. That way, you don't have to account for as many special characters in your filter criteria. In some cases, this may not be desirable e.g. if two senators from different parties and/or states share the same name but you only want one of them. As such, this is not a generalised solution. However, it appears this is not an issue for what you want to achieve.